# How to recover a corrupted objective C .m File .?

Tags: objective-c

The issue i faced today while working on my project at office.
The issue is that working with .m file suddenly PC restarted. After that when i opened that file its shows me XMl tags rather than objective c Code.
This mad me really shocked as i am unable to run my project.
Any one know solution to recover file.? It would be really appreciated.

Comment: That's why you should backup your computer and/or your project on a regular basis.  I think that there are recovery solutions available but t would be difficult.

Comment: Yeah no doubt always need to focuss on back up and commit code but unfortunately for some reason i could not.Is there any way to recover that file.??

Answer (score 0):

Well the only solution to this issue is to write code again.That is the reason you should back up your code and also use other tools like SVN to commit and update your code times and again to save the latest copy.